CSS Vertical Accordion working on Chrome iOS but not Safari iOS
I am developing a website using this open source code from CodePen
After spending a week working on it I realized that these Vertical Accordion Slides do not work Safari iOS (while they do work on Chrome iOS).
Strangely it does work on desktop Chrome AND Safari.
Can anyone help me make this compatible with Safari iOS?
I am happy to send a tip for the help.
Thank you.
It's required to post the code when linking to CodePen, so here you go (if you look on the CodePen site there is a section of comments at the top which is not posted below):
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;                        /* = free var 'height', need this to clip empty space at the bottom! */
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 5px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),5px -3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                                       /* '5px' comes from free var 'accordion-gutter' */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-100 {
   height: 100vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-90 {
   height: 90vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-80 {
   height: 80vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-70 {
   height: 70vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-60 {
   height: 60vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-50 {
   height: 50vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-40 {
   height: 40vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-30 {
   height: 30vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-20 {
   height: 20vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-10 {
   height: 10vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-0 {
   height: 0;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul {
   list-style: none;
   width: 32%;                            /* = 'slides' * 'tab-width' or, leave it fixed! ('.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.open' resets it to 100%) */
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   transition: all 500ms ease;            /* need this when we are entering vertically! */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: relative;
   /* need this to stop rapid opening of all subsequent slides when entering vertically! */
   overflow: hidden;                      
   -ms-transform: translate(0,0);         /* need this to apply 'position: fixed;' of navigation buttons! */
   -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
   transform: translate(0,0);
   transition: all 500ms ease;            /* need this when we jump from slide to slide! */
   background-color: #bfbfbf;             /* free var 'accordion-back-color' */
   padding: 0 0 0 5px;                    /* free var 'accordion-gutter' */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div {
   display: inline-block;                 /* might need this if '.accordion-text' is absolute! */
   width: 100%;                           /* goes with previous! */
   height: 50vh;                          /* = free var 'height' */
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 2px solid #808080;             /* = free var 'border' */
   border-radius: 10px;                   /* = free var 'radius' */
   background-color: #666;                /* free var 'tab-back-color' */
   /* need this if you have absolute positioned child nodes; also need it to 
      activate scrolling on those nodes! Side-effect: animation scrollbars in 
      relation with the 'scroll' class! Do NOT replace with 'translate(0,0)' as 
      the side effect is in navigation buttons that become un-fixed! */
   position: relative;
   background-position: left top;         /* free var 'img-position' for background images */
   background-size: cover;                /* might need this for background images */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;          /* might need this for background images */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-100 > ul > li > div {
   height: 100vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-90 > ul > li > div {
   height: 90vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-80 > ul > li > div {
   height: 80vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-70 > ul > li > div {
   height: 70vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-60 > ul > li > div {
   height: 60vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-50 > ul > li > div {
   height: 50vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-40 > ul > li > div {
   height: 40vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-30 > ul > li > div {
   height: 30vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-20 > ul > li > div {
   height: 20vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-10 > ul > li > div {
   height: 10vh;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-0 > ul > li > div {
   height: 0;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > :not([class*="accordion-text"]) {
  display: none;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP:not([class*="hover"]) > ul > li:hover > div {
   background-color: #868686;             /* free var 'tab-hover-back-color' */
}

/* 
 * Hover control class
 * -------------------
 */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul:hover > li {
  width: 8%;                              /* = free var 'tab-width' */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li:hover {
   width: 80%;                            /* = 100 - ('slides' - 1) * 'tab-width' or, leave it fixed! */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li:hover > div {
   background-color: #e9e9e9;             /* free var 'slide-back-color' */
   background-position: center;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li:hover > div > :not([class*="accordion-text"]) {
  display: block;
}

/* 
 * Open control class
 * ------------------
 */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.open > ul {
  width: 100%;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.open > ul > li {
  width: 8%;                              /* = free var 'tab-width' */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.open > ul > li.open {
   width: 80%;                            /* = 100 - ('slides' - 1) * 'tab-width' or, leave it fixed! */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.open > ul > li.open > div {
   background-color: #e9e9e9;             /* free var 'slide-back-color' */
   background-position: center;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.open > ul > li.open > div > :not([class*="accordion-text"]) {
  display: block;
}

/* 
 * Scroll control class
 * --------------------
 * Side-effect: animation scrollbars.
 * Solution: use js to apply inline style on animation start 'overflow: hidden;' 
 * and on animation end remove that style!
 */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover.scroll > ul > li:hover > div, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li.scroll:hover > div, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.scroll > ul > li.open > div, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li.open.scroll > div {
   overflow: auto;
}

/* 
 * Accordion text
 * --------------
 * It contains title used in tabs and body used when slide is displayed.
 * Uses 'pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov' for centering.
 */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   position: absolute;                    /* might need this */
   z-index: 100;
   padding: 0;
   height: 50vh;                          /* = free var 'height', this is critical! */
   width: 50vh;                           /* = free var 'height', this is critical! */
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-25vh + 50%);       /* = calc(-'height'/2px + 50%), this is critical! */
   transition: all 500ms ease;            /* might need this for 'accordion-text' animation on slide opening */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-100 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-50vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-90 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 90vh;
   width: 90vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-45vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-80 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 80vh;
   width: 80vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-40vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-70 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 70vh;
   width: 70vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-35vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-60 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 60vh;
   width: 60vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-30vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-50 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 50vh;
   width: 50vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-25vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-40 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 40vh;
   width: 40vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-20vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-40 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 40vh;
   width: 40vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-20vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-30 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 30vh;
   width: 30vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-15vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-20 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 20vh;
   width: 20vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-10vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-10 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 10vh;
   width: 10vh;
   margin: 0 0 0 calc(-5vh + 50%);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.h-0 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-text, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-text {
   /*position: static;*/
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover.no-open-text > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-text, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li.no-open-text:hover > div > .accordion-text,
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.no-open-text > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-text,
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li.open.no-open-text > div > .accordion-text {
   display: none;
}


/* 
 * Accordion title
 * ---------------
 * It is used as tab and slide title.
 * Uses 'pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov' for centering.
 */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-title {
   font-size: 2.5rem;
   color: black;                          /* free var 'tab-title-font-color */
   text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 10px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-text .accordion-title, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-text .accordion-title {
   display: inline-block;                 /* might need this to contract background color around title */
   font-size: 3rem;
   color: white;                          /* free var 'title-font-color' */
   text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);  /* free var 'title-open-back-color' */
}
 
/* 
 * Accordion body
 * --------------
 * It is used as text in slides.
 * Uses 'pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov' for centering.
 */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-body {
   display: none;
   color: white;                          /* free var 'body-font-color */
   text-align: justify;
   padding: 0 10px;
   margin: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);  /* free var 'body-back-color' */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-text .accordion-body, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-text .accordion-body {
   display: block;
}

/* 
 * Accordion images
 * ----------------
 * It is used in slides below accordion text and navigation arrows.
 */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-img {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   display: block;                        /* need this to always show images */
   width: auto;
   height: 100%;                          /* need this to fill tab vertically dictated by free var 'img-position' */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-img, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover.img-cover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-img, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.hover > ul > li.img-cover:hover > div > .accordion-img, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.img-cover > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-img,
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li.open.img-cover > div > .accordion-img {
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}

/* 
 * Background images
 * -----------------
 * Adjust it for your project.
 */
/*
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div { 
   background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/user/alexagorn/JIUjvqe2ZHg/450x200");
}
*/

/* 
 * Accordion navigation
 * --------------------
 * It is used in slides for navigation.
 */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 200;
   width: 100%;                           /* need this to expand fully inside the parent! */
   top: 50%;                              /* need this to center the container! */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a {
   /* you can't use one big navigation area as it blocks scrolling when mouse is
      over it! So, we break them to 2 small anchor areas! */
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #ddd;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: all 250ms ease;
   transform: translateY(-50%);           /* need this to center this child in the container! */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a.disabled {
   cursor: not-allowed;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a:nth-child(1) {
   left: 0px;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a:nth-child(2) {
   right: 9px;                           /* = 'accordion-gutter' + 'border' + 2px */
}
/* hover */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a:not([class*="disabled"]):hover {
   color: white;
}
/* 'fix-nav-scroll-overlap' */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.fix-nav-scroll-overlap > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a:nth-child(2) {
   right: 22px;                          /* = 'accordion-gutter' + 'border' + 2px + 13px  for scrollbars */
}
/* 'nav-circle', 'nav-square' */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-circle > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a {
   border-radius: 50px;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-circle > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-square > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);  /* free var 'nav-back-color' */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-circle > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a:not([class*="disabled"]):hover, 
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-square > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a:not([class*="disabled"]):hover {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);  /* free var 'nav-hover-back-color' */
}
/* 'nav-top' */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-top > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav {
   top: 0%;
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-top > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a {
   transform: translateY(2px);            /* = `border` */
}
/* 'nav-bottom' */
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-bottom > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 9px;                           /* = 'accordion-gutter' + 'border' + 2px */
}
.T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.nav-bottom > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav a {
   transform: translateY(-100%);
}

/* Reset for low width screens */
/* max width: 600px */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
   /* Basic code */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 {
      height: auto; 
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li > div > :not([class*="accordion-text"]) {
      display: block;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li > div, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600:not([class*="hover"]) > ul > li:hover > div {
      background-color: #e9e9e9;             /* free var 'slide-back-color' */
      background-position: center;
   }
   
   /* Hover, open control classes */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.hover > ul:hover > li, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.hover > ul > li:hover,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.open > ul > li,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.open > ul > li.open {
      width: 100%;
   }
   
   /* Scroll control class */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.scroll > ul > li > div, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li.scroll > div {
      overflow: auto;
   }
   
   /* Accordion text */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
      /*position: static;*/
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.no-open-text > ul > li > div > .accordion-text,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li.no-open-text > div > .accordion-text {
      display: none;
   }
   
   /* Accordion title */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-title {
      display: inline-block;                 /* might need this to contract background color around title */
      font-size: 3rem;
      color: white;                          /* free var 'title-font-color' */
      padding: 5px 10px;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);  /* free var 'title-open-back-color' */
   }
   
   /* Accordion body */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-body {
      display: block;
   }
   
   /* Accordion images */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li > div > .accordion-img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.img-cover > ul > li > div > .accordion-img, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li.img-cover > div > .accordion-img {
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
   }
   
   /* Accordion navigation */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600 > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.hover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-nav,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-600.open > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-nav {
      display: none;
   }
}
/* max width: 500px */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
   /* Basic code */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 {
      height: auto; 
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li > div > :not([class*="accordion-text"]) {
      display: block;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li > div, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500:not([class*="hover"]) > ul > li:hover > div {
      background-color: #e9e9e9;             /* free var 'slide-back-color' */
      background-position: center;
   }
   
   /* Hover, open control classes */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.hover > ul:hover > li, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.hover > ul > li:hover,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.open > ul > li,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.open > ul > li.open {
      width: 100%;
   }
   
   /* Scroll control class */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.scroll > ul > li > div, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li.scroll > div {
      overflow: auto;
   }
   
   /* Accordion text */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
      /*position: static;*/
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.no-open-text > ul > li > div > .accordion-text,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li.no-open-text > div > .accordion-text {
      display: none;
   }
   
   /* Accordion title */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-title {
      display: inline-block;                 /* might need this to contract background color around title */
      font-size: 3rem;
      color: white;                          /* free var 'title-font-color' */
      padding: 5px 10px;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);  /* free var 'title-open-back-color' */
   }
   
   /* Accordion body */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-body {
      display: block;
   }
   
   /* Accordion images */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li > div > .accordion-img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.img-cover > ul > li > div > .accordion-img, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li.img-cover > div > .accordion-img {
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
   }
   
   /* Accordion navigation */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500 > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.hover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-nav,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-500.open > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-nav {
      display: none;
   }
}
/* max width: 400px */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) { 
   /* Basic code */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 {
      height: auto; 
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li > div > :not([class*="accordion-text"]) {
      display: block;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li > div, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400:not([class*="hover"]) > ul > li:hover > div {
      background-color: #e9e9e9;             /* free var 'slide-back-color' */
      background-position: center;
   }
   
   /* Hover, open control classes */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.hover > ul:hover > li, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.hover > ul > li:hover,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.open > ul > li,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.open > ul > li.open {
      width: 100%;
   }
   
   /* Scroll control class */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.scroll > ul > li > div, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li.scroll > div {
      overflow: auto;
   }
   
   /* Accordion text */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
      /*position: static;*/
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.no-open-text > ul > li > div > .accordion-text,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li.no-open-text > div > .accordion-text {
      display: none;
   }
   
   /* Accordion title */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-title {
      display: inline-block;                 /* might need this to contract background color around title */
      font-size: 3rem;
      color: white;                          /* free var 'title-font-color' */
      padding: 5px 10px;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);  /* free var 'title-open-back-color' */
   }
   
   /* Accordion body */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-body {
      display: block;
   }
   
   /* Accordion images */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li > div > .accordion-img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.img-cover > ul > li > div > .accordion-img, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li.img-cover > div > .accordion-img {
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
   }
   
   /* Accordion navigation */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400 > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.hover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-nav,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-400.open > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-nav {
      display: none;
   }
}
/* max width: 300px */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) { 
   /* Basic code */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 {
      height: auto; 
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li > div > :not([class*="accordion-text"]) {
      display: block;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li > div, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300:not([class*="hover"]) > ul > li:hover > div {
      background-color: #e9e9e9;             /* free var 'slide-back-color' */
      background-position: center;
   }
   
   /* Hover, open control classes */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.hover > ul:hover > li, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.hover > ul > li:hover,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.open > ul > li,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.open > ul > li.open {
      width: 100%;
   }
   
   /* Scroll control class */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.scroll > ul > li > div, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li.scroll > div {
      overflow: auto;
   }
   
   /* Accordion text */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text {
      /*position: static;*/
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.no-open-text > ul > li > div > .accordion-text,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li.no-open-text > div > .accordion-text {
      display: none;
   }
   
   /* Accordion title */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-title {
      display: inline-block;                 /* might need this to contract background color around title */
      font-size: 3rem;
      color: white;                          /* free var 'title-font-color' */
      padding: 5px 10px;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);  /* free var 'title-open-back-color' */
   }
   
   /* Accordion body */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li > div > .accordion-text .accordion-body {
      display: block;
   }
   
   /* Accordion images */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li > div > .accordion-img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.img-cover > ul > li > div > .accordion-img, 
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li.img-cover > div > .accordion-img {
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
   }
   
   /* Accordion navigation */
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300 > ul > li > div > .accordion-nav,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.hover > ul > li:hover > div > .accordion-nav,
   .T73auXqB6A1R7oKOBA8BDesP.reset-max-300.open > ul > li.open > div > .accordion-nav {
      display: none;
   }
}

/**
 * pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov
 * ========================
 * Centers elements horizontally & vertically.
 * Ex.: <sth class="pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov">
 *         <x1 class="centered">...</x1>
 *         <x2 class="centered">...</x2>
 *      </sth>
 */
.pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov {
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}
.pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov > .centered, 
.pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov > .north,
.pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov > .south {
   display: table-cell;
}
.pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov > .centered {
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov > .north {
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
}
.pYLEi1aS9dFRUWLSptPEh7ov > .south {
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}


Slides do not work how? I actually tried the codepen on Safari iOS 18.1.it works for me.

Please could you describe what is supposed to happen that does not happen on IOS?

Basically the slides of the vertical accordion don’t open (the accordion stays shut). Here’s a video that shows the different behavior on iOS chrome (where the accordion opens) and iOS Safari (where it doesn’t open) on the same iPhone: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q2wUIIonD4BD9wV11EEE1auFv7z0rgpz/view?usp=drivesdk

I ran your codepen on Safari IOS 16 and it works same as your video shows for Chrome. Are you certain your Safari is picking up the right files, no caching for example?

Yes @AHaworth, I am certain. I just re-loaded it on Safari in a Private browser window and I even added a "&rand=1" at the end of the URL to make the URL unique... Safari on my iOS 17.6.1 in horizontal landscape orientation displays the vertical accordion slides but clicking on the slides has no change.
